# How to delete multiple sentencesfrom Microsoft word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

My word file contain some data which are following

```
#: app_s/accounting/admin.py:819
/Ingles/ "Detail Registers"
/Holandes/ "Registros detallados"

#: app_s/accounting/admin.py:831
/Ingles/ "Grouped per person"
/Holandes/ "Agrupado por persona"
```

**But I want to delete the portion of line which starting with #: app_s/ from every line. my output should be like that:**

/Ingles/ "Detail Registers"

/Holandes/ "Registros detallados"

/Ingles/ "Grouped per person"

/Holandes/ "Agrupado por persona"

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but an end-user question. As such it is off-topic at StackOverflow and should be asked in an appropriate end-user forum (e.g. MS Answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = #: app[!^11^13]@[^11^13]
Replace = nothing
```